# Rotate SCNNode relative local coordinates

Tags: scenekit, scnnode

I'm trying to rotate a node by `SCNAction`, but it rotates relative to parent’s coordinate space. Is it possible to rotate a node relative local's coordinate system?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure. You can obtain parent's space coordinates for rotation axis with [convertVector](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2867397-convertvector) method.

For example, this action will do 180 degrees rotation around local x-axis:

```swift
SCNAction.rotate(by: .pi, around: node.convertVector(SCNVector3(1, 0, 0), to: node.parent), duration: TimeInterval(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
[node runAction:[SCNAction rotateByX:0 y:1 z:0 duration:5.0]]; //Rotates the node along the y axis for 5 seconds.
```